# Build user avatar thumbnails after Drupal 5 to 6 to 7 upgrade

Tags: users, media

I'm upgrading a Drupal 5 site with nearly 100,000 accounts to 6 and then 7. After upgrade to 7 is complete I don't see user pictures/avatars displayed with user profiles or with forum posts/comments.

So far, I've confirmed that

- User pictures are set to display on posts/comments in the theme's settings.
- User pictures for new D7 accounts are stored, generated, and displayed.
- New user's pictures are generated and stored in sites/default/files/styles/thumbnails/.
- I've tried running drush "drush image-flush" without effect.

How can I force the generation of existing users' picture thumbnails?

Comment: Images are in the `sites/default/files/styles/thumbnails/` directory? Do you get a 404 or 403 on a comment listing page if you try to open the image url? Can you browse to an image directly in FF or Chrome or whatever by opening a page like `http://yoursite.com/sites/default/files/stypes/thumbnails/SOME_USER_PIC.jpg` ... ?

Comment: Original user pictures are stored in sites/default/files/pictures. These are browseable. Thumbnails for new user pictures are generated and stored in sites/default/files/styles/thumbnails/.

Comment: Are there entries in the `file_managed` table for each of the images, and does the `fid` column of rows in that table link up correctly with the `picture` column in the `users` table?

Comment: No, it appears that there is not. I checked just one user known to have a picture on the D5 site. To be honest, I didn't check user picture status after upgrading from D5 to D6. I'm still testing my upgrade scripts and will run them again and check user picture status in D6 before continuing onto D7.

Comment: This turned out to be a file path issue. I moved the files directory from it's original location, the Drupal installation root directory, to sites/default/files. Simply updating the file system path didn't change things. Creating a symbolic link from the Drupal root started to show avatars. I'll run a SQL update against managed_files as part of the upgrade.

Comment: I'm confirming this now and expect that thumbnails will be built during the D6 to D7 upgrade step with the addition of the symlink.